# Distributional product by $x$

Tags: distribution-theory

How does one prove that 
\begin{equation}
x T = 0 \Longleftrightarrow T = c \delta_0,
\end{equation}
with $T \in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$?

I see why we have "$\Longleftarrow$ 
" ($T = c\delta_0 \Leftrightarrow xT = xc\delta_0 \Leftrightarrow \langle xT, \phi \rangle  = \langle c\delta_0, x\phi \rangle$ for all $\phi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\langle \delta_0, x\phi \rangle = 0$ therefore $xT = 0$).

Comment: There is a slight complication here: defining the product of distributions isn't so well-defined.

Comment: For $g \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, one may multiply a distribution by $g$ I believe?

Comment: Yeah, it just may make the analysis a little murky, is what I meant. I'll see if I can answer the question at hand.

Comment: Another method would be to prove that the support of $T$ is a singleton $\{0\}$, and then use a theorem that distributions with singleton support are linear combinations of delta-distribution and its derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some details to work out, but here's a rough sketch. Let us apply Fourier transform techniques.

\begin{align}
0 &= \langle xT, \varphi\rangle \\
&= \langle T,x\varphi\rangle \\
&= \langle \mathcal{F}T, \mathcal{F}(x\varphi)\rangle \\
&= \langle \mathcal{F}T, (\mathcal{F}\varphi)'\rangle \\
&= -\langle (\mathcal{F}T)',\mathcal{F}\varphi\rangle
\end{align}

Thus the distribution $\mathcal{F}T$ has derivative zero. This implies that it is constant and the inverse Fourier transform of a constant distribution is a multiple of the Dirac delta at $0$.

---

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397538/reference-for-distributional-derivative-being-zero-implies-being-constant) are some details for showing that if the derivative of a distribution is zero, it is constant.

Comment: I think that you'd need to also add the fact that such a distribution is compactly supported, hence the Fourier transform is well-defined.