# does weak derivative zero imply independence?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

If $f\colon\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, and $\partial_x f = 0$ in the weak sense, i.e.
$$ \iint f(x,y) \partial_x \phi( x,y) dx dy =0 $$
for all $\phi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^2)$, does it follow that $f(x,y)=c(y)$?

Many thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Yes, it does follow. You can modify [this argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397538/reference-for-distributional-derivative-being-zero-implies-being-constant) to work in higher dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use functions $\phi \in C_\mathrm{c}^\infty (\mathbb{R}^2)$ of the form $\phi(x,y) = \chi(x) \psi(y)$ with $\chi, \psi \in C_\mathrm{c}^\infty (\mathbb{R})$ .

Since all functions are sufficiently nice, Fubini's theorem applies and we can conclude that
$$ \int \limits_\mathbb{R} \psi(y) \int \limits_\mathbb{R} f(x,y) \chi' (x) \, \mathrm{d} x \, \mathrm{d} y = 0 $$
holds for every $\psi \in C_\mathrm{c}^\infty (\mathbb{R})$ . Thus the continuous function $y \mapsto \int_\mathbb{R} f(x,y) \chi'(x) \, \mathrm{d} x $ vanishes identically for every $\chi \in C_\mathrm{c}^\infty (\mathbb{R})$ by the fundamental theorem of the calculus of variations.

But then for fixed $y \in \mathbb{R}$ the function $x \mapsto f(x,y)$ must be constant (see for example [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/958969/weak-derivative-zero-implies-constant-function) question) and equal to $c(y)$, say.

Since $f$ is continuous, we have $f(x,y) = c(y)$ for every $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ with $c \in C^0 (\mathbb{R})$ .

Comment: Thanks for the great answer :) I had been struggling to reduce this to the 1D case, and actually I think I managed a proof in the end after posting using a mollification argument, but your method is much cleaner and would work on more general domains :)